# Spark Streaming and Azure Event Hubs mapWithState

Tags: azure, apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

I've successfully integrated the code to pull messages off the event hub and process them through spark/spark-streaming.  I'm now moving onto managing state as the messages pass through.  This is the code I'm using, which for the most part is an adaptation of https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/spark/1.6/examples/Streaming%20mapWithState.html

Essentially this works with a dummy source, it works with a single stream on a single partition but it doesn't work for the unionised window stream.. While I could create multiple instances of the stream one for each partition it kinda defeats the point of the union and window.. + my attempts to get it working that way failed. I'm kinda stuck for inspiration on where to go now.. if anyone has any ideas that would be grand..

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").config(sparkConfiguration).getOrCreate()

val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkSession.sparkContext, Seconds(10))
streamingContext.checkpoint(inputOptions.checkpointDir)

//derive the stream and window
val eventHubsStream = EventHubsUtils.createUnionStream(streamingContext, eventHubsParameters)
val eventHubsWindowedStream = eventHubsStream.window(Seconds(10))

val initialRDD = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("dummy", 100L), ("source", 32L)))
val stateSpec = StateSpec.function(trackStateFunc _)
  .initialState(initialRDD)
  .numPartitions(2)
  .timeout(Seconds(60))

val eventStream = eventHubsWindowedStream
  .map(messageStr => {
    //parse teh event
    var event = gson.fromJson(new String(messageStr), classOf[Event])

    //return a tuble of key/value pair
    (event.product_id.toString, 1)
  })

val eventStateStream = eventStream.mapWithState(stateSpec)

val stateSnapshotStream = eventStateStream.stateSnapshots()
stateSnapshotStream.print()

stateSnapshotStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  import sparkSession.implicits._
  rdd.toDF("word", "count").registerTempTable("batch_word_count")
}

streamingContext.remember(Minutes(1))  

streamingContext
```

Comment: *it doesnt work for the unionised window stream.* What doesn't work?

Comment: Apologies, essentially the state function is never called.  i cant debug to that point.  When i use the sample code its fine.. and when i use a single stream its fine.. but not when  i use the unionised stream or the window..

Comment: Did you try debugging locally in your IDE?

Comment: Indeed, im debugging locally, this is successful with the basic example/word count.

Comment: Its odd, ive looked through the event hub streaming code and all looks ok, 

EventHubsUtils.createUnionStream

resolves to this code

 `val streams = (0 until partitionCount).map {
      i => createStream(streamingContext, eventhubsParams, i.toString, storageLevel)
    }
    streamingContext.union(streams)`

which returns a `DStream[Array[Byte]]`

and 

`eventHubsStream.window(Seconds(10))`

resolves to a `DStream[Array[Byte]]`

i can map that to a `DStream[(String, Int)]`  which i can invoke mapWithState etc on.. so as far as i can tell im constructing the code correctly

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue, in that i ended up using the direct stream and all my problems have gone away.  I had avoided this as the progress directory only supports HDFS or ADL and now i can no longer test locally.

EventHubsUtils.createDirectStreams(streamingContext, inputOptions.namespace,
      inputOptions.hdfs, Map(inputOptions.eventhub -> GetEventHubParams(inputOptions)))

Still, the union stream doesn't work..  Now i just need to figure out how to delete the progress directory in HDFS!!